# How can I quickly add a black outline to handwritten text?

Tags: layers, photo-editing

I'm working on creating a video somewhat like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWObWp1CrhE&t=47s) (In case you can't play the video, the video shows a chapter (known as Surah) of the Holy Quran called The Beneficient (known as Ar-Rahman), it shows handwritten text edited out of the Holy Quran to some footage which shows in the background, they also put an English translation above the Holy Quranic text) You see, I have the text from the Mushaf like this:

[image]

Then I remove the background, it'll look like this: [image]
I color it white.

[image]

I add it to an image.

[image]

Now please look at how some parts of (قُلْ) are in front of the cloud, so that it's a bit difficult to see. How can I *quickly* add a black outline to it so that the cloud doesn't affect it. Know that I need the process of adding a black outline to be *quick* because I will repeat the same process for all the words. I have heard of a procces where you copy the word, open a new layer, then enlarge the word, then color that word black, and then put the layer of the black word below the layer of the white word, but this takes too much time because I will be repeating this for all the words. Is it possible for me to create "slightly" black outline with one click or such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a shadow - it's a shifted black copy. I cannot read Arabic texts, but I guess it looks out readable if the background isn't full plain white with no variation:

[image]

This is tinkered in Inkscape, but I recommend you do it in the video editor. There you can save about 99% of the work, I guess. You have a track copy with two track effects:

- darken all to black
- shift

If you have an advanced video editor, you probably find the shadow as an effect like "Drop Shadow" in GIMP or many other image editors. This is in GIMP (sorry for inferior resolution, I had only your screenshot):

[image]

You need only few clicks, no matter how many texts you are going to show. Even your original rejected plan would be a small job in the video editor.

Of course you can change the used effects for different video sections. You simply add more tracks or insert the effects to the clips.

Comment: Jazak Allah khayran but how did you convert all the pixels in the text to white pixels?

Comment: @thatone dodobird The Inkscape version is traced to vector. Fill color is set white. The shadow is a black copy. There I tried also to add a stroke, but the result was not satisfactory, the stroke eated a part of the white area. The GIMP version got Color > Curves after removing the background. I lifted the left end of the curve up to white.

Comment: How can I select all the objects in GIMP? Because when I click "Select All" it selects the image, not the objects within the image. (I need all objects selected because I want to use the "Grow" option)

Comment: Nevermind, I found the "Select by Color" tool. But when I use it and click "Grow" it only grows the selection lines, not the pixels. How can I grow the pixels?

Comment: @thatonedodobird one possiblity: have a BIG brush and paint the selected area or pour from the paint bucket.  You can also blur the black area. Essentially this is one way to make a shadow, if you have the original as white in front of it.

Comment: Jazak Allah khayran, I have created this video (https://gofile.io/?c=UetDif), do you have any suggestions? For I see you an expert in this.

Answer (score 0):

Using Adobe Photoshop, you could...

Highlight the text layer...

Choose `Layer > Layer Style > Stroke` from the menu.

[image]

Adjust to your liking.

Comment: Which program is this?

Comment: @thatonedodobird Sorry,  it's Photoshop. If you are using specific software, you should edit your question and tag it with the appropriate software.

Comment: Jazak allah khayran, I have created this video (https://gofile.io/?c=UetDif) for I see you an expert in this, so do you have any suggestions?